# Find specific date in the current week

Tags: c#

How would I be able to get the date of the Thursday in the current week? For example, Thursday of this current week is 7/8/2010

Comment: ...unless your system happens to consider Friday to be the start of the week, in which case Thursday of this current week would be 7/15/2010.  Of course, it's very unlikely that a system considers Friday to be the start of the week, but it's not improbable for Monday to be the start of the week.  You may need to consider that, as you would get a different result on Sunday.

Comment: @Dr. W: Good point; the question should define what day the week is considered as starting on.  Usually it's Sunday, but it could reasonably be Monday.

Comment: I was just told earlier today that in Italy Monday is considered to be the start of the week.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this (alebit awkwardly) with the existing .NET DateTime. The trick is to use the `DayOfWeek` enum as an integer - since it denotes the days Sun - Sat in ascending numeric order (0-6).

```
DateTime someDay = DateTime.Today;
var daysTillThursday = (int)someDay.DayOfWeek - (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday;
var thursday = someDay.AddDays( daysTillThursday );
```

Or even more simply:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var thursday = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek).AddDays(4);
```

Comment: OK, I ran a test for 2 million iterations and my algorithm clocks in at 300ns and your algorithm (second part) clocks in at 200ns.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Interesting. Make sure in your performance test you account for JIT time by running each test case twice and discarding the first run's results. Otherwise you may see skewed results...

Comment: @LBushkin - Hmmm, I only dropped 1 run from the test.

Comment: I wouldn't expect either algorithm to be slow enough for anyone to care.

Comment: It didn't really make a difference. It is hard to get accuracy in the nanosecond level anyway without a more professional test.

Comment: Thanks to you and Curt for a great solution. It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Great solution. I made a small edit to the last line of the second example to use the DayOfWeek enum inside the AddDays method rather than the hardcoded value 4.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).AddDays(4)
```

Comment: Both you and LBushkin logged this answer within seconds of each other.  However, I gave him credit because his example was more efficient (just one call to Today) and he explained it.

Comment: And his answer will give the correct result within a few milliseconds of midnight, whereas mine won't.

Comment: Also true.  In fact, I think it's safe to generalize by saying that, if you intend to use the current timestamp more than once in a method, you should consider caching it to ensure that you're safe from edge conditions.  It's also (slightly) faster.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library: http://datetimeextensions.codeplex.com/

From the examples on the home page:

```
DateTime nextFriday = DateTime.Now.Next(DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

Comment: The OP is looking for the Thursday of this week, not the next time that day rolls around.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static DateTime GetDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    if (date.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
    {
        var direction = date.DayOfWeek > dayOfWeek ? -1D : 1D;
        do
        {
            date = date.AddDays(direction);
        } while (date.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek);
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to loop to get the answer.

Comment: @Steven - Please feel free to post an answer if you have a different algorithm.

Comment: I would, but others have beaten me to it.

Comment: For the record, the solution I had in my head was more complex than the successful one, but it was correct.  While I was working on simplifying it, I commented on your answer, but before I was ready to post, I saw that I'd be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to find *nearest* Thursday:

```
for 0 to 3 as x
    if today + x days is Thursday
        return (today + x days)
    if today - x days is Thursday
        return (today - x days)
```

Pseudo code to find Thursday this week:

```
lookForward = true
lookBackward = true
FirstDayOfTheWeek = Sunday

for 0 to 6 as x
    if today + x days is FirstDayOfTheWeek
        lookForward = false
    if today - x days is FirstDayOfTheWeek
        lookBackward = false
    if lookForward and today + x days is Thursday
        return (today + x days)
    if lookBackward and today - x days is Thursday
        return (today - x days)
```

Sorry, I don't speak C# :)

Comment: Hopefully it will be useful to someone else, looking for a solution in another language.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is fixed...
int thursday = 4;

int difference = thursday - (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

DateTime thursdayThisWeek = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(difference);
```